# Swift tableview to open and send Email

Tags: uitableview, email, swift

In swift, I have a tableview which consists of a contact list with emails and my goal is when you press a persons name, or I guess one of the cells, I want the email to pop up with their email in the "to recipient. I know how to do this to a button and make the button an action, but for the table view, I don't know exactly where to implement the action.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement it within the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method of the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

As previously suggested by Cihan Tek, you need to start with implementing didSelectRowAtIndexPath. It will be executed when you tap on a cell. Inside of it you need to determine the email address and show [MFMailComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/index.html). Use setToRecipients to add the email address to the "to: " field.

Comment: IBAction func mailForma(sender: AnyObject) {
        if (MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()) {
            
        mc = MFMailComposeViewController()
        var toRecipents = ["jforma@stonecrabsbaseball.com"]
        mc.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mc.setToRecipients(toRecipents)
        
        self.presentViewController(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
        }else {
            println("No Email was Found")
        }
    }

Comment: This is what I had as a button, can I essentially put this in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath? Or alter it at all

Comment: I think you can. You will want to determine the recipient from the selected row, though. The cellForRowAtIndexPath gives an index of the selected row, so you should be able to go to your data source and find element with that index and the appropriate email address.